# what is the difference between i+=i*i and i=+i*i in java?

Tags: java

what is the difference between

```
i+=i*i
```

and

```
i=+i*i
```

in java?

Can any one tell me what it the concept behind it. How internally it works?
I am getting different output of any value.

Comment: `+=` adds the value on the right hand side to the variable at the left hand side. `= +...` *assigns* the value on the right hand side. The `+` is part of the expression.

Comment: `+=` is the plussignment operator.  The value of the right-hand operand is added to the value of the left-hand operand.  `=+` is two separate operators: `=` and `+`.

Comment: `i += x` means "increase `i` by `x`". `i = +x` means "set `i` to x"

Comment: So you think ``+=`` and ``=+`` should be the same thing? why?

Comment: There is no `=+` operator.

Answer (score 3):

`i+=i*i` is equivalent to:

```
i = i + (i*i);
```

`i=+i*i` is equivalent to:

```
i = i * i;
```

Comment: specifically `i = +(i * i)` in case `i` is a complex number (not really, it doesnt make a number positive)

Comment: @StephenC well aware, I accidentally removed the `(unlikely)` part of my comment about it being a complex number when I added the `(not really...` part

Comment: Actually it would make no difference if `i` was complex.  The unary plus operator does not change the operand's sign.

Answer (score 2):

Let me parse this for you:

```
i += i * i     // uses the "plus and becomes" operator

i = +i * i     // uses the assignment operator and the unary plus operator
```

The first one is equivalent to

```
i = i + ( i * i )
```

The second one is equivalent to

```
i = i * i
```

(Actually, unary `+` operator causes "unary promotion" to occur.  This may result in unboxing and/or promotion to `int`, depending on the type of `i`.  However, in this example an equivalent promotion is is going to happen anyway for the operants of `*`, so the `+` has no net effect.)